# Connection must be valid and open SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

There was a problem. I checked the connection to the database - everything works.
But when I try to check the lines in the database, then the error pops up:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Connection must be valid and open." c#

How can i fix this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = GetDBConnection();
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 'rcc_base' WHERE login='" + this.textBox1.Text + "', pass='" + this.textBox2.Text + "' ;");
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            MessageBox.Show("Connection...");
            myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All nice");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `conn.Open` this line throws the erro ?

Comment: take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MySqlCommand` you are not using your `MySqlConnection` :( .So change it as follows

```
 MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM rcc_base WHERE 'login' ='" + this.textBox1.Text + "' AND 'pass' ='" + this.textBox2.Text + "' ;",conn);
```

Also , create a new instance of the `MySqlConnection` like :

```
  MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection;
  conn = GetDBConnection();
```

And a few suggestions:Your code is not good.Don't give direct values to columns in the SqlCommand rahter pass parameters like `@abc` , this will also prevent sql-injections.Sample :

```
  MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rcc_base WHERE login=@username AND pass=@password;",conn);

  selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@username",MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
  selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@password",MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

 ///Now to check if data exists in the database or not

 int count = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());

 if(count > 0)
  {
   ///data exists-login successful

  }
   else

  {
  ///data doesn't exists , login failed
   }
```

Also you should open the connection on form load so that you can access the database throughout the class/form.It is a better way to do it :)

Comment: Now i have: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''rcc_base' WHERE login='', pass=''' at line 1"

Comment: which method did u apply ?the 1st one or the last one ?

Comment: i use first because it is easier)

Comment: take a look at it now :)

Comment: Yes i try this 10 min ago... And:
"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException" в MySql.Data.dll
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''rcc_base' WHERE login='' AND pass=''' at line 1

Comment: Lol... i remove ' in 'rcc_base' and it works... Thank u for help :)

Comment: And i have a new problem...Anything i do, it still write "MessageBox.Show("Login failed");".

Comment: what is it ? ??

Comment: and ur code inside datareader makes no sense ... or should i say it's unnecessary...I'll edit my answer ....

Comment: re-check my answer

Comment: Have error on this: " MySqlDbtype.Varchar "
and this: " (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar; "

Comment: just change `selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@username",MySqlDbtype.Varchar).Value = usrnametextbox.text;` with `selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usrnametextbox.text);`,do it for password too

Comment: and for executeScalar,make sure ur sqlcommand includes `COUNT(*)` like i added

Comment: on executeScalar he say " Can not convert type "method" to "int" "

Comment: just add `()` after executeScalar`.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: "The specified cast is invalid." :(
on .ExecuteScalar()

Comment: i try this: int count = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
and all fine work...
Thank u my friend for ur help <3